# Why does this Bernstein-Vazirani solution use $ (-1)^{f(x)} $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I am reading a solution to the Bernstein-Vazirani problem. For those unaware, the issue is to find a randomly selected $ 0 \leq a \lt 2^n $ given only a function $ f(x) = a_0x_0 \oplus a_1x_1 \oplus ... = a \cdot x $ where $a_i$ and $ x_i $ represent the ith bits of $ a $ and $ x $ respectively.

The solution starts out with an n-bit input register and 1-bit output register. The output register is initialized to

$$
\textbf{HX}|0\rangle = \textbf{H}|1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)
$$

The next part of the solution, the part I don't understand, is that the author says that $ \textbf{U}_f $ applied to the conventional basis state $ |x\rangle_n|y\rangle_1 $ flips the value y if and only if $ f(x) = 1 $. Conceptually, this makes sense, but the author formalizes the above like so:

$$
\textbf{U}_f |x\rangle_n \textbf{H}|1\rangle = \textbf{U}_f |x\rangle_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle) = (-1)^{f(x)} |x\rangle_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)
$$

I don't understand how multiplication by $ (-1) $ is equivalent to flipping a bit here. To me, that would imply that the above is equal to (when $ f(x) = 1)

$$
|x\rangle_n (-1)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle) = |x\rangle_n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-|0\rangle + |1\rangle)
$$

This doesn't look like a bit flip because $ -|0\rangle \neq |0\rangle $

What am I missing?

Comment: Take the left side of the last equation and analyze what happens when you flip the last bit.  What do you get?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Isn't flipping the last bit equivalent to using $ \textbf{H}|0\rangle $ instead of $ \textbf{H}|1\rangle $ for the output register?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your last equation: Do you say that this is what you get when you flip a bit (and wonder why it is equal to the above), or are you saying that this is equal to the above (and wonder why it is what you get when you flip a bit)?

Comment: The book gives $ (-1)^{f(x)} |x\rangle_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle) $. Given that $ (-1)^{f(x)} $ is a scalar, I assume it can commute freely throughout the equation. Therefore, in the case that $ f(x) = 1 $, the equation given by the book is equivalent to $ |x\rangle_n (-1) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle) = |x\rangle_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-|0\rangle + |1\rangle) $. My question is that I don't understand how the formula I just derived above is equivalent to "flipping the output bit"

Comment: Is it because that $ -|0\rangle $, while not equivalent to $ |0\rangle $, is equally likely to produce a 0 classical bit when measured?

Comment: Have you tried taking |0>-|1> and flipping the bit? What do you get?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I don't understand what operation "flipping the bit" entails. I think that is the root of my confusion.

Comment: Flipping a classical bit maps $0\to1$ and $1\to0$. Flipping a qubit is the operation which maps $|0\rangle\to|1\rangle$ and $|1\rangle\to|0\rangle$.  So ... what does $|0\rangle - |1\rangle$ get mapped to?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. If you have spare time, would you mind checking my answer on this question to check if my derivation is correct?

Comment: Sounds perfect!

Comment: [Cross-posted to Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472915/why-does-this-solution-to-the-bernstein-vazirani-problem-use-1fx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answers lies in the definition of "bit flipping." Consider the bit flip operation on a single qubit:

$$
\textbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1 \\
    1       & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Applying $ \textbf{X} $ to $ \textbf{H}|1\rangle $ yields the answer

$$
\textbf{X}\textbf{H}|1\rangle =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1 \\
    1       & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1\rangle - |0\rangle)
$$